# Microsoft Message Analyzer - disable AutoIP feature (dns instead of ip address)

Tags: networking

I just installed Microsoft Message Analyzer, I'm trying to use it for the first time.
In the source/destination column it shows dns names instead of IP addresses.
I don't find anywhere an option to show just IP addresses, is there one somewhere?

Reading around in internet, it seems to me this is related to the new feature called "AutoIP" :

> Auto IP Address Resolution – this feature uses captured name
>   resolution network traffic and translates it into friendly names. For
>   instance, when a DNS request resolves 192.168.1.1 to MSN.COM, Message
>   Analyzer will now use that friendly name in the UI instead of the IP
>   address.

Answer (score -1):

Just add new columns  (right mouse button click - ")
["choose columns"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6E6u.png)